# Memory resouce monitoring program

Tags: shell-script, memory, monitoring, firefox, libreoffice

How to write a shell script to filter out the %Mem consumption of some process like Mozilla Firefox and LibreOffice Writer. Both values need to sum up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below command to find the same

```
ps axo %mem,command | egrep "Firefox | Writer" | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum =sum +$1}END {print sum}'
```

Comment: I had try it but command not found, the full question is like : The ps command is able to show the total Memory resource consumption in terms of percentage (shown in %Mem column). Write a shell script to filter out the %Mem consumption of Morzilla Firefox and LibreOffice Writer. Both values need to sum up and output it to a file called morzilla.log. Your script must be able to let the user to determine the period (how frequent) of monitoring the %Mem reading. Moreover, if the user intends to record down the reading every 4 seconds, the command shall be: ./monitor.sh 4

Comment: Its working fine for me                                                                                         ps axo %mem,command | egrep “process1|process1” | awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} {sum =sum +$1}END {print sum}'   As i checked in centos. kinldy confirm in which os you have checked

Comment: using fedora with virtual box

Comment: it works , answer is 4.1, how to make sure it is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not writing this in a script, I like htop http://hisham.hm/htop/ apt install htop

Otherwise use /proc/$PID/status

Comment: need to write it in script haha